# What conditions cause Tokyo Cabinet to block

Tags: python, blocking, tokyo-cabinet

I'm using Tokyo Cabinet with the `tc` module in python. I store my data in the TDB format. I expected the table to block only for the duration of a write. Unfortunately, I see that when the file is open with in the "writer mode", other processes cannot read from it. Is that a standard behaviour, wrappers problem, or am I doing something wrong? Or maybe there are other cases when the operations are blocked?

Comment: Is the Tokyo Cabinet bipartisan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [specification](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html):

> Tokyo Cabinet provides two modes to
>   connect to a database: "reader" and
>   "writer". A reader can perform
>   retrieving but neither storing nor
>   deleting. A writer can perform all
>   access methods. Exclusion control
>   between processes is performed when
>   connecting to a database by file
>   locking. **While a writer is connected
>   to a database, neither readers nor
>   writers can be connected.** While a
>   reader is connected to a database,
>   other readers can be connect, but
>   writers can not. According to this
>   mechanism, data consistency is
>   guaranteed with simultaneous
>   connections in multitasking
>   environment.

You have either create and close writer for each write operation or use Tokyo Tyrant to provide concurrent access.